# "If" and "Else" statements happening in the same "for" statement - Python

Tags: python, if-statement

I am somewhat new to Python so excuse me if this is an obvious mistake but after looking at many resources I cannot find a solution. What I want to happen is the code asks for 10 different letters (or any string technically), and if the letter typed isn't already in the array I.E. hasn't been typed before, it gets added to the array. The next time you type that same letter, it wouldn't add it to the array since that same letter is already in that array. this is my code:

```
ArrayLetter = ["INITIAL"]

for i in range(10):
    Letter = input("Letter: ")
    for i in range(len(ArrayLetter)):
        if ArrayLetter[i] == Letter:
            print("Letter already listed!")
        else:
            print("Not listed, adding letter to list!")
            ArrayLetter.append(Letter)
            break
```

This is a shortened output I get when testing this script:

```
Letter: A
Not listed, adding letter to list!
Letter: B
Not listed, adding letter to list!
Letter: A
Not listed, adding letter to list!
```

I hope this isn't too much of an obvious answer but as you can see, even though "A" is inputted twice, but keeps appending it to the array.

Thanks!

Comment: You're using the variable `i` in both of your loops, use different variables (`j` in the inner loop for example)

Comment: Try tracing through your logic with pencil and paper. For example, consider your `for i in range(len(ArrayLetter)):` loop. Under what conditions can you logically break out of that loop prematurely? If you see a letter in the existing list that doesn't match the input letter, can you *immediately* conclude that the letter should be added? Why or why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to enclose the `ArrayLetter` with list, and you can also remove the nested loop:

```py
ArrayLetter = "INITIAL"

for i in range(10):
    Letter = input("Letter: ")
    if Letter in ArrayLetter:
        print("Letter already listed!")
    else:
        print("Not listed, adding letter to list!")
        ArrayLetter += Letter
```

`if Letter in ArrayLetter:` checks if the letter is already in the string. `ArrayLetter += Letter` appends the letter to your `ArrayLetter`

Comment: why the `+=` instead of `.append()`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `in` when checking if your string in in the list.

```
ArrayLetter = ["INITIAL"]

for i in range(10):
    Letter = input("Letter: ") 
    if Letter in ArrayLetter:
        print("Letter already listed!")
    else:
        print("Not listed, adding letter to list!")
        ArrayLetter.append(Letter)
```

Answer (score 0):

script:

```
ArrayLetter = ["INITIAL"]

for i in range(10):
    Letter = input("Letter: ")
    if Letter not in ArrayLetter:
        print("Adding to array")
        ArrayLetter.append(Letter)
    else:
        print("Letter already present")
```

Output:

```
tackoverflow abhishekphukan$ python3 1.py 
Letter: INITIAL
Letter already present
Letter: a
Adding to array
Letter: A
Adding to array
Letter: A
Letter already present
```

Note 'A' and 'a' are treated as separate values.